# JavaFX run from constructor.

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to use this class in order to run a media file using only the constructor , without a main method. 
(Im running this Player class from a GUI) how can i use luanch() without a main method?

```
public class Player extends Application {
    File file = null; // a file to play. 

    public Player (File file){
        this.file = file;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL               url  = file.getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toURL(); // URL path of the file.
        final Media       m    = new Media(url.toString());
        final MediaPlayer mp   = new MediaPlayer(m);
        final MediaView   mv   = new MediaView(mp);

        final DoubleProperty width  = mv.fitWidthProperty();
        final DoubleProperty height = mv.fitHeightProperty();

        width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "width"));
        height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "height"));

        mv.setPreserveRatio(true);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(mv);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 960, 540);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        mp.play();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by calling the static method of the class that extends Application. So calling  `Player.launch(Player.class)` should do it. Also notice that it must not be called more than once or an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Hi , then if i would like to run a specific file like given in the consturctor?

Comment: @oprezyzer: Starting at the constructor is a bit tricky for subclasses of `Application`, since javafx allows only a single application to run. It would be beneficial to keep the application class as small as possible and move most of the logic to a different class not extending `Application` (e.g. a factory). This way you can use that code without requiring your class to be launched and do not have problems the "one application class only" restraint.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.launch` is the method that starts the application. You can only start one application. Any application launched using this method needs to supply a non-arg constructor, which is used in the application lifecycle to construct the application class. You cannot use a instance of the application class constructed yourself.

You can pass `String`s as parameters however and use the `getParameters` method to access those parameters:

```
public static void startPlayer(File file) throws MalformedURLException {
    Application.launch(Player.class, file.toURI().toURL().toString());
}
```

#### `Player` class

```
private String url; // a file url to play. 

public Player() {
}

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    url = getParameters().getUnnamed().get(0);
    // TODO: handle invalid parameters
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws MalformedURLException {
    final Media m = new Media(url);
    ...
```

## Alternative

Create a non-application `Player` class and use it from a application class. This allows you to create more than one player window in a application and be more or less independent of the application lifecycle:

```
public class AlternativePlayer {

    public AlternativePlayer(Stage primaryStage, File file) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url = file.getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toURL(); // URL path of the file.
        final Media m = new Media(url.toString());
        mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
        final MediaView mv = new MediaView(mp);

        final DoubleProperty width = mv.fitWidthProperty();
        final DoubleProperty height = mv.fitHeightProperty();

        width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "width"));
        height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "height"));

        mv.setPreserveRatio(true);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(mv);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 960, 540);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    }

    private final MediaPlayer mp;

    public void play() {
        mp.play();
    }

}
```

With this approach you also need a running application, so this is what it could look like:

```
public class PlayerMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws MalformedURLException {
        AlternativePlayer player = new AlternativePlayer(primaryStage, new File("myvideofile"));

        primaryStage.show();
        player.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is totally correct but what about calling a singleton of this Player class providing the file?

some code could be the following (in your Player class):

```
private static Player instance;
public static Player getInstance(File file) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Player(file);
    }
    return instance;
}

private Player (File file){
    this.file = file;
}
```

Then use it in another class by calling

```
Player.getInstance(new File("test.file")).launch(Player.class);
```